# How to delete figures in python-ggplot?

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

python ggplot is awsome, but I have trouble with a memory problem.

```
import pandas as pd
from ggplot import *


data = pd.DataFrame({"date": [1, 2, 3],
                     "value": [10, 20, 30]})

for i in range(30):
    gg = ggplot(aes(x='date', y='value'), data=data) + geom_point(alpha=0.5)
    print(gg)
    f = "fig{}.png".format(i)
    ggsave(f, gg)
```

this code displays RuntimeWarning(ggplot-0.4.7).

```
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:412: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_num_figures`).
```

How can I delete old figures ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot uses matplotlib's pyplot interface. You can close all the existing pyplot figures with:

```
# Importing this library as plt is a convention, same
# importing numpy as np, or pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')
```

ggplot is still in a pretty early stage of development, so hopefully some of these issues will get smoothed over as it gets closer to a stable release.

Comment: this works well, thank you! and "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" line doesn't need, because "from ggplot import *" loads plt variables.

Comment: Then you have an old version, that problem with leaked imports should be fixed in the newer version (could be that this fix is not yet in a released version).

Comment: @Jasc: I think 0.5.0 was only released very recently (I think within the last week or 2), and OP is a version behind on 0.4.7.